# Multiple find in set

Tags: mysql

For multiple find in set I use:

```
... 
FROM Table1 a, Table2 b
WHERE CONCAT(',',REPLACE(a.options,',',',,'),',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',REPLACE(b.options,',',',%,'),',%')

a.options = '1,2,3,4,5' VARCHAR()  
b.options = '2,5,6,9,10' VARCHAR()
```

Digits in `a.options` and `b.options` are always sorted in ascending order.
As the result:

```
WHERE ',1,,2,,3,,4,,5,' LIKE '%,2,%,5,%,6,%,9,%,10,%'
```

It works well but it's not fast.
How to make this query faster?

Comment: 1. Normalize your data.

Comment: @Strawberry What did you mean?

Comment: What do you mean what do I mean? ;-)

Comment: Now I have 2 tables with 170 and 8000 rows. When I normalize data I get more 500000 rows in each tables. I'm not sure that it would work faster.

Answer (score 0):

Like and string manipulation on the SQL set will be slow as soon as there is some data to talk about.. No matter what. You should maybe rethink why you need to do this or change the table structure. 
I solved one problem like this by having a calculated column that did all the pre calculations on insert and then persisted that. So I did the query on the calculated column instead.